# Automatically extended imported data

Tags: google-sheets, jira

I have a sheet in which data records are automatically added every day (in the morning) from Jira using the plugin [Jira Cloud for Sheets](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/use-jira-cloud-for-sheets/). 36 fields of the issues in Jira are retrieved.

I supplement that data myself on the basis of vlookup and other sheets.
An example:

in another sheet I have the following table:

[image]

In my sheet with data from Jira I receive the "startedDate" from an issue in Jira. Based on that date I retrieve the sprint from the other sheet.

The problem is that every time in the morning the extra issues are added, but not the extra data from vlookups or others.

Then the sheet looks like this:

[image]

How can I ensure that the data is automatically completed when new records are added automatically?

Comment: One option might be to convert your formulas into array formulas. We already have several questions about this. If you need further help, please add more details like one of the formulas directly into the question body. If you have many very different formulas you might have to post multiple questions. Another option might be to use Google Apps Script (Spreadsheet Service and on change installable trigger). If you are interested in this option, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

Comment: Worked with Apps Script! Thanks.